# Should complete user story be implemented by one team in context of microservices archicture

Tags: microservices, user-story, use-case

I have implemented application using microservices architecture. I take a user story to implement. This involves front end/UI, and two microservices to implement the user story. So I have three components involved. Should one team implement the user story, or should the user story be split among three teams.
It is possible that three components are using different technologies. Front end is in Javascript, one microservice is in Java, and the other microservice is implemented in C#.NET. Somehow, I feel, ideally, one team should implement the complete user story. This is more efficient, and reduces communication overheads. But since three components are in different technologies, it doesn't seem feasible, and I guess the user story has to be split into three parts. What should be approach. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've answered your own question here.

> I feel, ideally, one team should implement the complete user story. This is more efficient, and reduces communication overheads.

Precisely right. If you can have one team with a high level of cohesion implement the whole solution then there is less communication overhead, likely less documentation overhead and the cost of change is lower.

> But since three components are in different technologies, it doesn't seem feasible, and I guess the user story has to be split into three parts.

If you are utilising components in multiple technologies that are already managed by other areas of the business, then you might be stuck. The cost of changing the organisational structure is probably higher than the communication overhead to have the front-end team co-ordinate with two other teams.

Context is everything.

If those components don't already exist, then why not build them in technologies covered by a single team's capability?